# Fix Simple jQuery Function Element Show Only On Scroll

Tags: jquery, fadein, fade, fadeout

Here is the code below:

```
(function($){
var $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function(){
    if ($window.scrollTop() >= 162) {
        $('.small-logo').fadeOut();
    }
    else {
        $('.small-logo').fadeIn();
    }
 });
}(jQuery));
```

the function only works when scrolling how do I get the small logo to not show on load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your css

```
.small-logo { display: none; }
```

Or if you necessarily want to do it with jquery(why?)

```
(function($){
$(".small-logo").hide();
var $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function(){
    if ($window.scrollTop() >= 162) {
        $('.small-logo').fadeOut();
 }
 else {
    $('.small-logo').fadeIn();
 }
});
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Which one did you try? The css or the jquery?

Comment: the display:none worked but for some reason the jquery option didn't

Comment: @Jessica As long as it works :) Besides, CSS is the cleaner way anyway. If the user has javascript disabled the element would be shown initially but with CSS the element would never be displayed onLoad.